# Set of zeros of polynomial in several complex variable.

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, several-complex-variables

**Question**: the question is already asked here(link→[If $p(z,w)=a_0(z)+a_1(z)w+\dots +a_k(z)w^k$ are non constant polynomial.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/400545/168676))

$p(z,w)=a_0(z)+a_1(z)w+\dots +a_k(z)w^k$ where $a_i(z)$ are non constant polynomials in complex variables with  $k\ge 1$.

I need know if $$\{(z,w):p(z,w)=0\}$$

which of these are true or false:

> $1$. bounded with empty interior
>
> $2$. unbounded with empty interior
>
> $3$. bounded with non empty interior
>
> $4$. unbounded with non empty interior

**they said that answer is (b)** But, **Wikipedia** says, zero sets of complex analytic functions in more than one variable are never discrete (link→https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function?wprov=sfla1 other reference [Why are there no discrete zero sets of a polynomial in two complex variables?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/25556/168676))

**So how could zero set of** $p(z,w)$ **in** $\mathbb{C×C}$ **have empty interior if it is never discrete?** Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see a contradiction. For instance, in $\mathbb{R}^2$ the set $\{(x,0)\,|\,x\in\mathbb{R}\}$ has empty interior and it is not discrete.

Comment: Sir, first of all thank you for making it clear. Sir can we prove the zero set of $p(z,w)$ has empty interior, by using Identity theorem in $\mathbb{C×C}$?

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi Sure. The identity theorem works in that context too.

Comment: Thank you so.. much sir :-)